# Swift 4 Conversion Segmentation Fault: 11

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

Need help converting some code to Swift 4. Starting getting errors and not sure how to convert this piece of code. I am having trouble with `String` and `doubleValue`.

```
let distanceInMeters: Double = userLocation.distance(from: businessLocation)
let distanceInMiles: Double = ((distanceInMeters.description as? String).doubleValue * 0.00062137)
let distanceLabelText = "\(distanceInMiles.string(2)) miles away"
```

[image: Segmentation Fault 11 File]

Comment: Why are you converting a `Double` to `String` and then back to `Double` again?

Is `let distanceInMiles: Double = distanceInMeters * 0.00062137` not enough?

Comment: I was thinking that ".doubleValue * 0.00062137" is needed to complete creating the distance from the user and displaying it in a UILabel.

Comment: I am converting "distanceInMeters" to "distanceInMiles" so its easier to read for the user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are converting a `String` back and forth unnecessarily. Moreover, you should use `String` formatters to print doubles with a given precision.

Here is your code in a cleaner format:

```
let distanceInMeters = userLocation.distance(from: businessLocation)
let distanceInMiles = distanceInMeters * 0.00062137
let distanceLabelText = String(format: "%.2f miles away", distanceInMiles)
```

Comment: Swift is a type inferred language. There is no need to specify the same type returned by the distance(from:) method which it is already a Double. You could also use Swift Measurement model type to properly convert from meters to miles and vice versa. `Measurement(value: 1, unit: UnitLength.meters)
    .converted(to: .miles).value`. // 0.0006213727366498068

Answer (score 1):

`distanceInMeters` is a `Double`, which you try to convert to `String`, which you then try to convert back to `Double`. Why? Just do

```
let distanceInMiles: Double = distanceInMeters * 0.00062137
```

As for

```
distanceInMiles.string(2)
```

Double no longer has a `string` method - just use `String`s initializer

```
let distanceLabelText = "\(String(distanceInMiles)) miles away"
```